# 'list' object is not callable python

Tags: python-3.x

```
numbers = [
    951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544,
    615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941,
    386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345,
    399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217,
    815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717,
    958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470,
    743, 527]


count=0
while numbers(count)==527:
    print(numbers(count))
    count+=1
```

may in know what is the error in above code?
what is meant by "'list' object is not callable"
please correct the code
thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use square brackets? e.g. `numbers[count]`. Also, you may need to change the `==` to `!=`

Comment: Aside from the syntax error, you need to decide what your program is actually trying to do.   Are you trying to count how many 527s there are at the start of `numbers`?  Are you trying to count the number of 527s in `numbers`?  If the latter, ask yourself what will happen with your `while` loop, because `numbers[0] == 951`..

Answer (score 0):

`numbers(count)` replace on `numbers[count]`

```
count=0
while numbers[count]!=527:
    print(numbers(count))
    count+=1
```

If you want print all numbers except last:

```
for item in numbers[0:-1]:
    print(item)
```

Comment: This will run, but you should point out that it won't *do anything*.

Comment: Hence my `!=` comment

Answer (score 0):

`while numbers(count)==527:` means that `numbers` is interpreted as a function with one argument, `count`.  `numbers` is actually a list object, so when the interpreter tries to call the 'function' it will return the error you're seeing.

You need to use `[]` for indexing and slicing.

Your revised code would look like this:

```
numbers = [
    951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544,
    615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941,
    386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345,
    399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217,
    815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717,
    958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470,
    743, 527]


count=0
while numbers[count]!=527:
    print(numbers[count])
    count+=1
```

This will print every item in `numbers` up until you get to the first instance of 527.